# Get file directory using username and password

Tags: io, azure-virtual-machine, directoryinfo, azure-virtual-network, networkcredentials

I have a series of virtual machines deployed to an Azure virtual network that are connected to our on-premise server so that we can access the application via the UNC \10.101.1.5 which is mapped to a config variable "Input Folder"

Due to the change in architecture the following code is no longer being accessible via the network credentials of the signed in user and I want to pass a username and password into the directory info search is this possible?

'Get all the files in the input directory
Dim directoryInfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("InputFolder"))
Dim files As IO.FileInfo() = directoryInfo.GetFiles()

Is there any way I can pass the network credentials in to the DirectoryInfo method?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this directoryInfo class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.DirectoryInfo(v=vs.110).aspx ? If so then there isn't a way to pass network credentials in.

What your options are depends on how much freedom you have to change the app and the architecture. For example setting up a file copy, storing files as Azure blobs and accessing them via URI/SAS key.